# RTL's TypeError: _react2.screen.getAllBy is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my project I am successfully using `render` and `screen` from `@testing-library/react`, However everytime I do `screen.getAllBy` or `screen.getByRole` or anything else other than `getByText` I am getting such errors. One of them was,

```
typeerror: _react2.screen.getAllBy is not a function
```

This occurred upon the usage of `screen.getAllBy`.

My imports includes,

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom;
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';
```

Am I missing an import or is there something wrong with my code?

```
it (`Testing Component`, () => { 
  render(<BrowserRouter><TestComponent /></BrowserRouter>
  expect(screen.getAllBy('li')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAllBy` is just one of the variants of the queries. Complete query would be  `getAllByLabelText, getAllByRole` etc. Check the [react-testing-library docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries) about Queries.

Comment: Read the documents a few times before. End result of having too many thoughts at parallel. Surprised that I missed such a trivial detail. -.-